# how to generate module debuginfo package

Tags: kernel-module

I'm developing a kernel module. To debug the module, i want to make a debuginfo packet, like kernel-debuginfo-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm.But i did not find the method of production. Please help me!